# jQuery, $(element).click doesn't work on ie<9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, events

I have a click event with jQuery like that :

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#id_secteur_activite").click(function () {    
        console.log('ok');    
    });
});
```

On firefox and ie9, when i click on my element `#id_secteur_activite`, i have the message "ok" in my console.

But when i test on ie 8 and ie7, i have nothing. .click doesn't work on ie<9.

Do you have any ideas ? thanks !

Edit :

```
<SELECT id=id_secteur_activite name=secteur_activite>
<OPTION selected value="">choisissez d'abord un secteur d'activité</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: What is `#id_secteur_activite` ? -- please show your HTML

Comment: it's a <select>. But it's he same with another element i think.

Comment: How are you checking the console in IE<9 ?

Comment: I just click F12 .. ^^

Comment: how about .on("change"... instead?

Comment: I just want to retrieve an event when i click, or change or something else on my select.

Comment: If it's a `select`, I'd suggest using the `change` event rather than `click`. Provided you're using jQuery 1.7+ you can use `.on('change', function(){...});`

Comment: I get OK in IE8 here: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8t8Jh/show/

Comment: i have tried your code and its working fine in internet explorer 7 and 8.

Comment: jquery version used? v2.0 does not support IE < 9

Comment: Why `click` to select? use `change` with `jquery version 1.9`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `.on()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#id_secteur_activite").on('click',function () {
        alert('ok');    
    });
});
```

and also use `alert` instead of `console`.

Comment: I have  
TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
$("#id_secteur_activite").on('change', function(){

Comment: @ClémentAndraud that means you have older version of jquery update jquery version to 1.9

Comment: Hmm, should have posted my comment as answer... click also works in 1.9

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO(http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8t8Jh/show/)

All works using a high enough version of jQuery (here edge which is currently v1.9.2pre)

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
/*    $("#id_secteur_activite").click(function () {    
        console.log('click');    
    });
*/    
    $("#id_secteur_activite").on("click",function () {    
        console.log('click');    
    });
    $("#id_secteur_activite").on("change",function () {    
        console.log('change');    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use both `click` event and  `change` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#id_secteur_activite").on('change',function () {    
        console.log('ok');    
    });
});
```