# jQuery click event not fired on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

For my project I use two browsers IE(ver11) and chrome.

I create buttons on my page and bind click event to every button.

Here the button that I create on UI:

```
  <table id="miniToolbar">
      <tbody>
        <tr>             
            <td><button type="button" class="button_air-medium"><div id="showToolbar" class="miniToolbarContant showMenu"></div></button></td>
            <td><div id="toolbarArea" class="toolbarArea" data-Owner="dera" data-Date="11/2016"> 
                <img id="toolbarTitle" width="15px" height="15px" src="../stdicons/threePoints.png">
              </div>
            </td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="button_air-medium"><div id="showLayers" class="miniToolbarContant showLayers"></div></button>
            </td>
        </tr>                                       
      <tbody>
  </table>
```

And here is javascript events bounded to each button:

```
$(function() {  
    $('#showToolbar').click( function(){ 
        $(this).toggleClass('rotate');
        $('#toolbarArea').toggle('slide');

        $(this).toggleClass('showMenu');            
        $(this).toggleClass('hideMenu');
    });

    $('#showLayers').click( function(){ 
        $(this).toggleClass('rotate');          
        hideLagend();          
        $('#InfoBand').toggle('slide');      

        $(this).toggleClass('hideLayers');          
        $(this).toggleClass('showLayers');
    });             
});
```

When I use chrome and I click on the button the appropriate method is fired and it works perfect.
But while I open on IE and click on the button no method is fired and I don't get any errors in console.

Any idea why method doesn't fires on IE?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the known `.click` event not registering correctly on IE issue.

Try using `.on("click"...` rather then `.click`:

```
$(function() {  
    $('#showToolbar').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('rotate');
        $('#toolbarArea').toggle('slide');

        $(this).toggleClass('showMenu');            
        $(this).toggleClass('hideMenu');
    });

    $('#showLayers').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('rotate');          
        hideLagend();          
        $('#InfoBand').toggle('slide');      

        $(this).toggleClass('hideLayers');          
        $(this).toggleClass('showLayers');
    });             
});
```

Comment: Per [jQuery's documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/), `.click` method is a shortcut for `.on( "click"`. So your suggestion will just refer back to what he already has

Comment: @BenRondeau Nope. IE has known issues with `.click`. Please check the facts before downvoting.

Comment: Documentation of this bug?

Comment: @BenRondeau There's no official docs. But, search through SO and you'll see many posts regarding this.

Comment: @BenRondeau https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381959/jquery-element-click-doesnt-work-on-ie9

Comment: @BenRondeau Also, I'm talking from experience. It's a known issue I had problems with myself on IE.

Comment: This would be a major bug - that internet explorer does not support a click event. The posts I see on stack overflow relate more to needing to wrap a jQuery click event in `document.ready` handler. Not trying to fight you on this - just see what the issue is.

Comment: @BenRondeau I'm well aware of the `document.ready` issue - the OP did use, and I'm also aware of the glitchy `.click` event for IE. Let's wait to see what the OP is saying. In the meantime, removing your downvote would be appreciated. I promise to delete my answer completely if this does not resolve the issue.

Comment: I can't remove the downvote until the answer is edited (SO blocks me from doing it).

Comment: @BenRondeau Edited.. Thanks

Comment: Koby, thanks for post IO tryed your attitude but it doesn't works.

Comment: @Michael are you fetting any errors in the dev console?

Comment: @Michael What happens if you add an `alert('clicked');` above the line `$(this).toggleClass('rotate');` ?

Comment: @KobyDouek I think I found the problem.I need to move Id from div to the button element